# Automatic logout of Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account

Gmail is logging me out of all of my mail accounts with the following alert message:

> You have been signed out of this account.
>
> This may have happened automatically because another user signed in from the same browser. To continue using this account, you will need to sign in again. This is done to protect your account and to ensure the privacy of your information.

I have two factor turned on for one of the accounts I am getting punted from. Googling the error has not turned up anything overly enlightening. Aside from clearing cookies and cache suggestions for a fix?

Comment: are you using the same browser to log into the second account?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep yes I am

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the message as you are trying to access multiple Gmail accounts from the same browser. Google has provided a solution for this—you can sign in to multiple accounts at once using the *Add Account* option. For more details check out [this Google Help link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1721977?hl=en).

Comment: Every so often I get caught by this, I'll have another account signed in but the window is in a different workspace and I've forgotten about it. I sign in to my other account, open up all my tabs and docs etc then BAM, sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Another option I have used is the multiple profiles feature of Google Chrome. You can have independent Google Chrome profiles open at the same time. They have separate bookmarks, apps, cookies etc, so you can be logged into any website (including Gmail) under two different user IDs without any unwanted interactions.